# How to make Javascript generated checkboxes persist?

Tags: javascript, ruby, ajax, checkbox

The "ajax" in the script sends a post or delete message to the server. The javascript, which contains the ajax, is what adds the checkboxes. How can we make the created checkbox elements persistent so when a user refreshes the page they are still there?

[image]

**habits/_form.html.erb**

```
<label id="<%= @habit.id %>" class="habit-id"> Missed: </label>
<% @habit.levels.each_with_index do |level, index| %>
  <% if @habit.current_level >= (index + 1) %>
    <p>
      <label id="<%= level.id %>" class="level-id"> Level <%= index + 1 %>: </label>
      <%= check_box_tag nil, true, level.missed_days > 0, {class: "habit-check"} %>
      <%= check_box_tag nil, true, level.missed_days > 1, {class: "habit-check"} %>
      <%= check_box_tag nil, true, level.missed_days > 2, {class: "habit-check"} %>
   </p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**habit.js**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var handleChange = function() {
    habit = $(this).parent().prev().attr("id");
    level = $('label', $(this).parent()).attr("id");
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "/habits/" + habit + "/levels/" + level + "/days_missed",
        method: "POST"
      });
    } else {
      $.ajax({
        url: "/habits/" + habit + "/levels/" + level + "/days_missed/1",
        method: "DELETE"
      });
    }
    if (!$('input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)', $(this).parent()).length) {
      /* this is just an example, you will have to ammend this */
      $(this).parent().append($('<input type="checkbox" class="habit-check">'));
      $(this).parent().append($('<input type="checkbox" class="habit-check">'));
      $(this).parent().append($('<input type="checkbox" class="habit-check">'));
      $(".habit-check").on('change',handleChange);
    }
  }
  $(".habit-check").on('change',handleChange);
});
```

**habit.rb**

```
class Habit < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :comments, as: :commentable
    has_many :levels
    serialize :committed, Array
    validates :date_started, presence: true
    before_save :current_level
    acts_as_taggable
    scope :private_submit, -> { where(private_submit: true) }
    scope :public_submit, -> { where(private_submit: false) }

attr_accessor :missed_one, :missed_two, :missed_three

    def save_with_current_level
        self.levels.build
        self.levels.build
        self.levels.build
        self.levels.build
        self.levels.build
        self.save
    end

    def self.committed_for_today
    today_name = Date::DAYNAMES[Date.today.wday].downcase
    ids = all.select { |h| h.committed.include? today_name }.map(&:id)
    where(id: ids)
  end 

    def current_level_strike
      levels[current_level - 1] # remember arrays indexes start at 0
    end

    def current_level
            return 0 unless date_started
          def committed_wdays
            committed.map do |day|    
              Date::DAYNAMES.index(day.titleize)
            end
          end

          def n_days
            ((date_started.to_date)..Date.today).count do |date| 
              committed_wdays.include? date.wday
            end - self.missed_days
          end     

      case n_days     
          when 0..9
            1
          when 10..24
            2
          when 25..44
            3
          when 45..69
            4
          when 70..99
            5
          else
            6
        end
    end
  end
```

**days_missed_controller**

```
class DaysMissedController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]

  def create
    habit = Habit.find(params[:habit_id])
    habit.missed_days = habit.missed_days + 1
    habit.save!
    level = habit.levels.find(params[:level_id])
    level.missed_days = level.missed_days + 1
    level.save!
    head :ok # this returns an empty response with a 200 success status code
  end

  def destroy
    habit = Habit.find(params[:habit_id])
    habit.missed_days = habit.missed_days - 1
    habit.save
    level = habit.levels.find(params[:level_id])
    level.missed_days = level.missed_days - 1
    level.save!
    head :ok # this returns an empty response with a 200 success status code
  end
end
```

Here's the **gist** of it: https://gist.github.com/RallyWithGalli/c66dee6dfb9ab5d338c2

Please let me know if you need any further explanation, code, or pictures :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method is using local storage (stored in the users browser). That feature exists in modern browsers, so when you don't need to support legacy browsers, it is the best option.

The usage is also unbelievable simple, just set and read attributes on the "localStorage" variable:

```
# Set one value
localStorage.myapp_level1_flag1 = true;

# read the value
if (localStorage.myapp_level1_flag1) {
   ...
}
```

You of course should give the variables meaningful names. The values assigned to localStorage will be saved across sessions. There is also a variable "sessionStorage" that saves data only for one session.

Also the data is separated by the domains it was set. So domain X can not access data set by domain Y.

Local Storage is supported roughly since IE8 and has the advantage over cookies, that the data is not transmitted to the server on every request. Before local storage existed, cookies where used, with some performance overhead attached.

**Integration**

I would recommend the integration of the local storage at two positions in your code (if I understand your JS outline right):

> (of course, you say, that you don't understand JS to much, that makes
>   the thing much more difficult, because the solution hinges completely
>   on local storage at the browser side -- but else you would need to
>   transfer all the data from your server side (which could be necessary
>   in the long run to prevent data duplication))

First position: When you create the check boxes (just a rough example how it could be):

```
if (localStorage.habit_level1_flag1) {
    $(this).parent().append($('<input type="checkbox" class="habit-check" checked>'));
}
else {
    $(this).parent().append($('<input type="checkbox" class="habit-check">'));
}
```

The other position is at the change handler:

```
if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/habits/" + habit + "/levels/" + level + "/days_missed",
    method: "POST"
  });
  localStorage.setItem("habit_"+habit+"_"+level, true);
} else {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/habits/" + habit + "/levels/" + level + "/days_missed/1",
    method: "DELETE"
  });
  localStorage.setItem("habit_"+habit+"_"+level, true);
}
```

Look here for more information about [localStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/Html/html5_webstorage.asp).

Comment: Thank you Juergen for your well thought out explanation :) I just don't see how  I can integrate it with the code I provided. You said its unbelievably simple, I sure hope you're right. Do I put it at the top of habit.js? I'm unfamiliar with the inner workings of javascript. It's a language I haven't taught myself yet, but I was hoping to get this one feature done before launching my app.

Comment: I added some rough integration hints. But you may also think if you want to store the information on the server and pull it from there in a similar fashion (at the creation of the check boxes make a reading AJAX-call).

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com: Sorry forgot to address you and I don't know, if you get a flag without. Read my previous comment.

Comment: Thanks again @Juergen! I hear you loud and clear. When I added the first option to different places in the file it didn't funky stuff, probably just because it was a rough example. I like the 2nd option more because its more of an integration, although that had no effect from what I can see. I'm surprised this would be so difficult and I thought I got over the hard part with humble rumble's answer :/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30109624/how-to-call-3-new-checkboxes-upon-checking-3-old-checkboxes?lq=1

Comment: Don't expect a complete solution from StackOverflow. That is not the reason it exists. When you don't know how to adapt the JS part, you are really in a bad situation. I think, it might be better to find somebody with JS expertise that can help you with the relevant AJAX calls.

Comment: Yea I'm 95% done with my app and just need a few more changes that are beyond my scope of knowledge. If I try to teach myself I feel like it will take me months I do not have so in the short-term I'm trying to ask around. Do you have any suggestions on where I could go to get full answers? Preferably free, but I'm willing to pay a few bucks if that's what it will take.

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com: Thanks for the upvote. I am sorry, that I lack the time to help you. I thought, that JS knowledge is rather widespread. Some AJAX-calls with jQuery is also not that complicated. Of course, when you program in Ruby it needs some adaption, since JS today heavily relies on callback functions. A programming style that seems a little weird at first. Of course it depends on the country you live in. I guess, there are many web-programmers around that can do some JS. Currently it would take up to much of my time to deliver a complete solution to you. Sorry.